# CallerFilePathAttribute not returning file path with valid directory separators on azure's linux container app service

Tags: linux, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have the following method in a  netcore2.1 web app:

```
public static void Information(string message, [CallerFilePath] string filePath = "")
{
    var fileNameWithoutExtn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
    . . .
}
```

When running on azure app service (windows host) it behaves as expected:

> filePath =
> C:\web\src\production\MyWebsite\Controllers\ChallengeController.cs
>
> fileNameWithoutExtn = ChallengeController

But, when I run this on azure's linux container app service:

> filePath =
> C:\web\src\production\MyWebsite\Controllers\ChallengeController.cs
>
> fileNameWithoutExtn  =
> C:\web\src\production\MyWebsite\Controllers\ChallengeController

And

> Path.DirectorySeparatorChar = /
>
> Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar = /
>
> Path.PathSeparator = :
>
> Path.VolumeSeparatorChar = /

Why is CallerFilePath giving me a path which does not match with DirectorySeparatorChar or AltDirectorySeparatorChar  ?

PS: I posted the same in [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1923fe26-2ff9-4f33-bfa4-60dbe71fd252/callerfilepathattribute-not-returning-file-path-with-valid-directory-seperators-on-azures-linux) but did not get any response, hence posting here. I will update here if I hear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because:

a) Linux uses '\' as directory separator, while Windows uses '/'
b) CallerFilePath returns the path on compile time. The code was compiled on Windows, not on Linux.

So you get `filePath = C:\web\src\production\MyWebsite\Controllers\ChallengeController.cs`

A workaround for this is write your own method to get file name, like:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char DirectorySeparatorChar='\\';

        string path = @"C:\web\src\production\MyWebsite\Controllers\ChallengeController.cs";

        string fileName = GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path, DirectorySeparatorChar);

    }

    public static String GetFileName(String path,char DirectorySeparatorChar)
    {
        if (path != null)
        {
            int length = path.Length;
            for (int i = length; --i >= 0;)
            {
                char ch = path[i];
                if (ch == DirectorySeparatorChar )
                    return path.Substring(i + 1, length - i - 1);

            }
        }
        return path;
    }

    public static String GetFileNameWithoutExtension(String path, char DirectorySeparatorChar)
    {
        path = GetFileName(path, DirectorySeparatorChar);
        if (path != null)
        {
            int i;
            if ((i = path.LastIndexOf('.')) == -1)
                return path; 
            else
                return path.Substring(0, i);
        }
        return null;
    }`
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed the part 'CallerFilePath returns the path on compile time'. Now, this is clear.